# how to install sql server 2008 after renew window

Tags: sql-server

I had installed sql server express with server name in drive 'D'. Now i have renew window of my pc. When i install again sql server then it will give option to enter server name. But i want to use already exist server name and data. How it will possible?

Comment: I think it's a stretch asking this question on Stack Overflow.  Maybe you should post it on http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/.  Also, you picked two incorrect tags.  SQL stands for structured query language and is applicable across many platforms, server is a running instance of a software application capable of accepting requests from a client and giving responses accordingly.  There is a "SQL-Server" tag that is appropriate.

Comment: Ok if you understand then reply my question